# How to rotate a list such that item selected from the list always gets the middle position in a list view

Tags: java, android, list, listview, collections

I don't know if I did any mistake while rotating the list or something else needs to be done..I would appreciate it very much if anyone could help me on figuring out the solution.

I have a vertical `ListView` with 5 items(in the left side of the screen-shots) as shown in the screen-shots:
[image: The Look when the app starts in the beginning.]

[image: The List rotates downwards and "Home Player" comes in the mid when up button is pressed.]

[image: The List rotates upwards and "Internet" comes in the mid when down button is pressed.]
As you can see the list should be rotated each time an item is clicked or selected.The problem is that the code that i have implemented works with `onItemClickListener`(when the item clicked is one position below or above the item in the middle),but it doesn't work with `onItemSelectedListener`(the list rotates for two times (for a single direction) then stops rotating in that direction,  meaning `onItemSelected` is not called at all).

May be more screen shots will make it clear:
[image: The list rotated in upward direction after pressing the down button and stopped rotating after it rotated for two times]

[image: The list(which was not rotating list on down press) rotates when pressed up button,but rotates downward first as shown in the screen-shot.]
Well this might make you more confused though.. I want a list whose selected item takes the middle (Text Color Blue) position and the list rotates accordingly.
Please Help.... Thanks a Lot.

**Source Code: Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



      private ListView categoryList;
    ListCustomAdapter listadapter;
      private List<TextItem> txtItems;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     categoryList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listCategories);
     listadapter=new ListCustomAdapter(this,txtItems);
            categoryList.setAdapter(listadapter);
    categoryList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    listadapter.getPosition(i);
                    Log.d("position",""+i);
                    if(i>2) {
                        Log.d("position1",""+(i-1));
                        Collections.rotate(txtItems, 4);
                        listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }else if(i<2){
                        Log.d("position2",""+(1-i));
                        Collections.rotate( txtItems,1);
                        listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    else{

                    }

                }
            });



            categoryList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    Log.e("inside" ,"onItemSelected");
                    if(i>2) {

                        Collections.rotate(txtItems,4);
                        Log.d("position rotated",""+i);
                        listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }else if(i<2){
                        Collections.rotate( txtItems,1);
                        listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }



                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                Log.e("inside" ,"onNothingSelected");
                }
            });
    }
```

**ListCustomAdapter:**

```
   public class ListCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<TextItem> txtItems;
        int pos;

        public ListCustomAdapter(Activity activity, List<TextItem> txtItems) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.txtItems = txtItems;
        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return txtItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
            return txtItems.get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        /*
        inflate the items in the list view
         */
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;


            if (inflater == null) {
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vertical_list_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
                holder.listLayout= (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_layout);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            if (pos == position) {
                Log.d("translated","done of position"+pos);
                holder.category.setTranslationX(10.17f);

            } else {
              /*  view.imgViewFlag.getLayoutParams().height = 140;
                view.imgViewFlag.getLayoutParams().width = 300;*/
                holder.category.setTranslationX(1.0f);
                Log.d("translated","default of position"+pos);
                // view.imgViewFlag.setBackgroundResource(0);
                holder.category.setBackgroundResource(0);

            }
            TextItem model = txtItems.get(position);
            holder.category.setText(model.getTitleName());

            if(position==2)
                holder.category.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);




        /*
        creating objects to access the views
         */

            return convertView;
        }
        public void getPosition(int position) {
            this.pos = position;
        }
        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView category;
            LinearLayout listLayout;

        }
    }
```

Comment: you will have to store the current position of list item so that on rotation it can get the same item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my code works fine for OnItemClickListener, I figured out that the item that's clicked is set as selected in the list..so for OnItemSelectedListener... I had to make the middle position as selected all the time .. Hence,I added the following

```
categoryList.setSelection(2); /*2 is the mid position for the list with 5 items *\
```

after the  list was rotated i.e:

```
categoryList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Log.e("inside" ,"onItemSelected");
                if(i>2) {

                    Collections.rotate(txtItems,4);
                    categoryList.setSelection(2);
                    Log.d("position rotated",""+i);
                    listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }else if(i<2){
                    Collections.rotate( txtItems,1);
                    categoryList.setSelection(2);
                    listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }



            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            Log.e("inside" ,"onNothingSelected");
            }
        });
```